# Error installing MySQL-Python on Mac

Tags: python, macos, mysql-python, easy-install

I tried to install the MySQL-Python library for development with Django, but always show any errors in the different ways:

**With PIP:**

```
rigo:~ rigobcastro$ sudo pip install MySQL-Python
Downloading/unpacking MySQL-Python
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/MySQL-Python/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:503: error:0D0890A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_verify:unknown message digest algorithm>
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/MySQL-Python/ when looking for download links for MySQL-Python
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:503: error:0D0890A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_verify:unknown message digest algorithm>
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download links for MySQL-Python
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/MySQL-Python/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:503: error:0D0890A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_verify:unknown message digest algorithm>
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/MySQL-Python/ when looking for download links for MySQL-Python
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement MySQL-Python
No distributions at all found for MySQL-Python
Storing complete log in /Users/rigobcastro/.pip/pip.log
```

**With easy_install:**

```
rigo:~ rigobcastro$ sudo easy_install MySQL-Python
Searching for MySQL-Python
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/MySQL-Python/
Reading http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python
Reading https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1
Best match: MySQL-python 1.2.4
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.4.zip#md5=ddf2386daf10a97af115ffad2ed4a9a0
Processing MySQL-python-1.2.4.zip
Running MySQL-python-1.2.4/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-mx6sxJ/MySQL-python-1.2.4/egg-dist-tmp-XMcHdk
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.28.tar.gz
Extracting in /tmp/easy_install-mx6sxJ/MySQL-python-1.2.4/temp/tmp9GMCmz
Now working in /tmp/easy_install-mx6sxJ/MySQL-python-1.2.4/temp/tmp9GMCmz/distribute-0.6.28
Building a Distribute egg in /private/tmp/easy_install-mx6sxJ/MySQL-python-1.2.4
/private/tmp/easy_install-mx6sxJ/MySQL-python-1.2.4/distribute-0.6.28-py2.6.egg
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-null-conversion"
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'llvm-gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
rigo:~ rigobcastro$
```

With the llvm-gcc-4.2 error I tried install XCode and its command line tools and GCC solution.

I have Python 2.7.4 and Mac OSX Lion 10.7.5.

Comment: It should be `pip install mysql-python` for pip.

Comment: @Hedde This error is not for Camelcase http://pasteboard.co/2rRlUXiL.png Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a SSL related issue.
Here you can find the explanation.
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/829

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned before me....getting Python to work with MySQL on a Mac is a ?@#$@&%^!! nightmare.

Installed Django framework on Mac OS 10.7.5 initially from the original Django website and when the MySQLdb didn't work, and after many hours googling and trying solutions from SO, I have installed the Django stack from BitNami http://bitnami.com/stack/django

Still, got the issues mentioned above and then some more...

What helped me eventually is what Josh recommends on his blog:
http://joshbranchaud.com/blog/2013/02/10/Errors-While-Setting-Up-Django.html

Now Python 2.7 is finally connected to MySQL 5.5